# Doing groupby on cell values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with 99 columns from dx1-dx99 one column as LOS. dxi columns contain categorical codes and they don't have any order. Codes can occur in any column in a row. Codes can repeat in a column but they will not repeat in a row:

```
dx1 dx2 dx3 .   dx99    los
E10 I12 0 N18 R18       12
E10 I12 I31 E44 N17     7
E10 I12 N17 T86 0       5
I12 E10 N18 A04         1
E10 I12 B10 N18 Z99     4
E10 N18 Z76             1
E10 N18 Z99 N25 E78     8
```

I want to calculate average of LOS for each code in the data frame. All I found was I can apply groupby() function on multiple columns. But that doesn't give me desired result. I need result in this format:

```
Codes    mean-LOS
E10      5.42    
I12      7.6
N18      5.2
.
.
etc.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) for reshape with `groupby` and aggregate `mean`:

```
df = df.melt('los', value_name='Codes')
#older version of pandas < 0.20.0
#df = pd.melt(df, 'los', value_name='Codes')
df = df.groupby('Codes', as_index=False)['los'].mean()
print (df)
   Codes        los
0      0   8.500000
1    A04   1.000000
2    B10   4.000000
3    E10   5.428571
4    E44   7.000000
5    E78   8.000000
6    I12   5.800000
7    I31   7.000000
8    N17   6.000000
9    N18   5.200000
10   N25   8.000000
11   R18  12.000000
12   T86   5.000000
13   Z76   1.000000
14   Z99   6.000000
```

If need rename column:

```
df = df.melt('los', value_name='Codes')
df = df.groupby('Codes')['los'].mean().reset_index(name='mean-LOS')
print (df)
   Codes   mean-LOS
0      0   8.500000
1    A04   1.000000
2    B10   4.000000
3    E10   5.428571
4    E44   7.000000
5    E78   8.000000
6    I12   5.800000
7    I31   7.000000
8    N17   6.000000
9    N18   5.200000
10   N25   8.000000
11   R18  12.000000
12   T86   5.000000
13   Z76   1.000000
14   Z99   6.000000
```

Comment: I am getting error data frame object has no attribute 'melt'. Is this due to new version of pandas has this method? I have '0.17.1'.

Comment: exactly, `df.melt` is implemented in `0.20.0` version.